# Android RelativeLayout align_below not enforced when aligning on TextView?

Tags: android, alignment, android-relativelayout

I'm finding issues with keeping elements in a `RelativeLayout` in their proper order.

I'm trying to achieve the following element placement:

```
Date
<DatePicker>
Value <EditText>
Description <EditText>
```

See the screenshot below for a better idea of what it looks like:

[image]

The issue is that the `Description` label (`TextView` with id `label_description`) and related `EditText` element show on top of the `DatePicker`, when it has `android:layout_below="@id/edittext_value"`.

Changing this to `android:layout_below="@id/label_value"` (align below the text label, instead of the `EditText` element) seems to work, but I'd still like to understand what's happening here.

It happens the same in the Eclipse editor and the running app.

Any idea what is wrong here?

The XML is below.

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/add_expense"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <!-- Date: field -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/label_field_date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datepicker_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/label_date"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:calendarViewShown="false" />


    <!-- Value: field -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/label_date"
        android:layout_below="@id/datepicker_date"
        android:text="@string/label_field_value"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/label_value"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/label_value"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"/>

    <!-- Description: field -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/label_value"
        android:layout_below="@id/edittext_value"
        android:text="@string/label_field_description"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/label_description"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/label_description"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete"/>


   <!-- buttons -->

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_OK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:text="@string/label_button_addexpense_OK" />

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/button_OK"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/label_button_addexpense_clear" />

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/button_OK"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/label_button_addexpense_cancel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/add_expense"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<!-- Date: field -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Date"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datepicker_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/label_date"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:calendarViewShown="false" />

<!-- Value: field -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/datepicker_date"
    android:text="Value"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/label_value"
    android:layout_below="@+id/datepicker_date"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/label_value"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<!-- Description: field -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label_description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/label_value"
    android:text="description"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext_description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/label_description"
    android:layout_below="@+id/label_value"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label_description"
    android:inputType="textAutoComplete" />

<!-- buttons -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_OK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:text="Ok" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_clear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_OK"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Clear" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_OK"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Cancel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside relative layout use linear layout and split the page with different part by using android:layout_weight=" ". set orientation without fail. If not works let me know i will give another solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Date: field -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Date"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datepicker_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/label_date"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:calendarViewShown="false" />

<!-- Value: field -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/datepicker_date"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:text="Value"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext_value"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/label_value"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label_value"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<!-- Description: field -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label_description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/label_value"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext_description"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/label_description"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label_description"
    android:inputType="textAutoComplete" />

<!-- buttons -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_OK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:text="OK" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_clear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_OK"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="ADD" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_OK"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Cancel" />
```

Answer (score -1):

try using @+id/ instead of @id/, cause sometimes that's the ssue

Answer (score -1):

In the `TextView` with id `label_description` change

```
android:layout_below="@id/edittext_value"
```

to

```
android:layout_below="@id/label_value"
```

Comment: Can anyone please explain how i can improve this?